# State is getting logged as undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting files from my input: `other = event.target.files;` which starts as a global variable and console.logs as `FileList {0: File, 1: File, 2: File, 3: File, length: 4}`. I'm adding this to my state(this.state.songList, which starts as null) and `if(this.state.songList != null)` I'm adding the list of songs from `this.state.songList` to my FormData.

```
.then(()=> {
this.setState({songsList : other})

 }).then(()=> {

   if(this.state.songList != null) {
   Array.from(this.state.songsList).forEach(song => {
    data.append('songs', song);
  })
 }

console.log(other);
console.log(this.state.songList)
})
```

For some reason the code inside the if statement almost never gets ran because `this.state.songList` is always undefined in the console. If I run the code in the second .then without the if statement it gets ran and adds my files to the FormData so I know for a fact that `this.state.songList` is not empty in my second `.then`.

Why does the code in the second `.then` not get ran when the `if(this.state.songList != null)`  is surrounding it although it gets ran without so I know it doesn't equal null and what can I do to fix this issue of state getting read as null.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into this issue because `setState` is an async function that won't necessarily update by the time your `then` executes. You should use the callback function for `setState` to do whatever you need to do with the new value.

```
this.setState({
  songlist: other
}, () => {
  // code to execute after the songs update in state

  if(this.state.songList != null) {
    Array.from(this.state.songsList).forEach(song => {
      data.append('songs', song);
    })
  }
})
```

Hopefully that helps!